# How to set a different Http Status in loopback 4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I can't find any ressources on how to change the success HTTP code using loopback 4.

For example :

201 "created" on post method

204 "no content" on delete method

I tried to specify this in the @api decorator but this change is not reflected in the actual response.

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I can't find any ressources on how to change the success HTTP code using loopback 4.

We don't have first-class support for this feature yet. The current workaround is to inject the Response object into your controller method and set the status code directly via Express/Node.js core API.

```js
export class TodoController {
  constructor(
    @repository(TodoRepository) protected todoRepo: TodoRepository,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) protected response: Response,
  ) {}

  async createTodo(@requestBody() todo: Todo): Promise<Todo> {
    this.response.status(401);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import `Response` and `RestBindings` from `@loopback/rest`, and `inject` from `@loopback/core`. Add the below imports in your controller.

```
import { Response, RestBindings } from '@loopback/rest';
import { inject } from '@loopback/core';
```

> 201 "created" on post method

See the discussion in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/788. The difficult part is how to figure out what URL to send in the `Location` response header.

> 204 "no content" on delete method

Just change your controller method to return `undefined` instead of the current `{count: 1}` object. I believe this is the default behavior for CRUD controllers scaffolded by our `lb4` tool.

```js
export class TodoController {
  // ...
  @del('/todos/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '204': {
        description: 'Todo DELETE success',
      },
    },
  })
  async deleteTodo(@param.path.number('id') id: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.todoRepo.deleteById(id);
  }
```

Comment: Miroslav, this is not working for me. For this `this.response.status(200)`, I am getting the error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli where is your `Response` type coming from? Did you import it from `@loopback/rest`? Until recently, we had to include `dom` in TypeScript's `libs`  config and as a result, `Response` was also defined as a global type. Such global DOM `Response` has different members than `Response` object provided by Express & Node.js

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš Its working now, after importing `Response` from `@loopback/rest`. Edited the answer too. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, is there a way I can get faster response for my questions from loopback team. We have a production service running on loopback 4. And we have been making lot of changes, and as a result facing challenges in development and debugging.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš How to mock `Response` while writing unit test for the controller. Getting the following error `Type '{ status: SinonStub<any[], any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': sendStatus, links, send, json, and 72 more. [2740]
let response: Response` when I try to mock the response instance `response = { status: sinon.stub()}`

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli You can get faster support by buying IBM Advance Support  for Runtimes, see https://developer.ibm.com/node/support/. Regarding your second about mocking Response, please open a new StackOverflow question for that.